# Why is ALTER TABLE slow for PostgreSQL when using CHECKs in DB domains?

Tags: postgresql

I found out that:

- adding a column with a default value is fast
- adding a column with a check is fast
- adding a column using a DB domain with a default value is fast
- **adding a column using a DB domain with a check is slow**

It seems to me that Postgres uses domains correctly for default values however I do not understand why using a CHECK directly on a column is fast but using a DB domain slow.

How to test that (tested on PG12 and PG15)

```sql
-- Create a table with 1M rows
CREATE TABLE "test_1" ("id" BIGINT);
INSERT INTO "test_1" ("id") SELECT generate_series(1, 10000000);


-- Add new column with default value
ALTER TABLE "test_1" ADD COLUMN "value_def_1" SMALLINT DEFAULT 0;
-- Result: instant response


-- Do the same thing with a DB domain (data type).
-- Create a domain, add a column which has the new domain as a data type.
CREATE DOMAIN "value_default" AS SMALLINT DEFAULT 0;
ALTER TABLE "test_1" ADD COLUMN "value_def_2" "value_default";
-- Result: instant response


-- Add another column which has a CHECK
ALTER TABLE "test_1" ADD COLUMN "value_check_1" SMALLINT CHECK ("value_check_1"= ANY (ARRAY[1, 2]));
-- Result: Not instant, around 10 % of the time of the first insert (1 million rows)


-- Do the same thing with a DB domain.
-- Create a domain, add a column which has the new domain as a datatype.
CREATE DOMAIN "one_or_two" AS SMALLINT CHECK (VALUE = ANY (ARRAY[1, 2]));
ALTER TABLE "test_1" ADD COLUMN "value_2" "one_or_two";
-- Result: Around 100 % of the time of the first insert.
```

Comment: Look at the resulting table.  The domain default doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that adding a column with default value sets this value to all existing cells however the new column with default just in domain does not. It keeps the cells as NULLs and checks just the newly inserted values.
I not concerned about the defaults now but with the speed of domains and checks.

Comment: Not every optimization which it is possible to implement has actually been implemented.  The check constraint defined in the table needs to scan the whole table, while the one defined in the domain needs to rewrite the whole table.  Arguably PostgreSQL should be changed to avoid both of those, but that isn't really a suitable topic for stackoverflow.  See https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-hackers/ if you want to write code yourself, or https://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-general/ to just propose a new feature.

Comment: I thought those two ways (check on column and check on domain) produce same result and that the result is achieved in a same way (and time). If this is the reason, I am OK with that: "The check constraint defined in the table needs to scan the whole table, while the one defined in the domain needs to rewrite the whole table."